# vb script to Access password protected connection

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, passwords, odbc

I have simple script:

```
Option Explicit
dim oaccess
set oaccess = createobject("access.application")
oaccess.opencurrentdatabase "C:\test.mdb"
oaccess.docmd.runmacro "MacroOne"
oaccess.closecurrentdatabase
oaccess.quit
set oaccess=nothing
```

But in this scenario macro will run query that connects to password protected table.
So when trying to execute macro I have a message:

Oracle ODBC Driver Connect
Service Name, User Name, Password

Now does anyone know how to implement this into my vb script? So it will automatically put those details and run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you use a DSN in your Access database for the linked table in Oracle.
You should switch to a DSN-less ODBC connection. There is no GUI support for this feature and requires some back-dooring. Please read [this](http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/DSNLessLinks.html) article and decide for yourself if you are going to go this path. If you decide to go, check [this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle#oracle-in-oraclient11g_home1) website for examples on how to create a DSN-less connection to Oracle.

Comment: Thank you cha. I am not an administrator of the database therefore I cannot make any permanent changes to it. As a user/analyst I can only connect and pull the data. This login message is quite frustrating so I have to find a way around it :/